# Sets with nonempty infinitieth derived set

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Define the infinitieth derived set of a set $A$ as the intersection of all n-th derived sets of $A.$

**What can the infinitieth derived set of $A$ look like? In particular, I am interested in $A\subset S^1$ compact.**

The types of infinitieth derived sets I can think of are (some) disjoint unions of closed intervals* and Cantor sets.

*even here, I'm not sure about the exact statement: can an isolated point be the infinitieth derived set of $A$? My intuition says no, but intuition isn't a proof.

Comment: Can you give an example where the second derived set differs from the first?

Comment: @GregMartin $\{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Answer (score 1):

[Embedding the countable ordinal $\omega^{\omega}$ as a bounded subset of the real line $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123981) (and then adding the unique limit point) gives an example of a compact set whose "infinitieth derived set" is a point.